# Custom Salesforce Registration Lightning Comp For Community User

Tags: lightning, community, salesforce1-app

How to create a custom lightning Registration component for the community user with Name, Email, password & confirm password for the community user.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to below image:

1. Go to Setup > Community builder
2. In top left (below image), go to `Login`. Remove the standard component shown there
3. Drag and drop your component from `CUSTOM COMPONENTS`

For your custom component to show in the list:

1. For Aura component, implement interface [forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes/documentation)
2. For LWC component, configure meta file with [lightningCommunity__Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_community_builder) in `targets`

[image]